# how to switch from a frame to another frame

Tags: python, tkinter, frame

I'd like to switch from the rating_frame to the summary_frame. How would I do this? Would I destroy the rating_frame? I want to go onto the rating_frame by clicking the 'Show' button.

I have a search frame that is staying there. I only want the rating frame to change.
I have not yet made a start on the summary_frame as I don't know how to change from the rating_frame or where I would write it. Could you give me a good foundation?

Here is my Wireframe:
[image]

Here is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Movie:
    def __init__(self, movie):
        self.movie = movie
        self.ratings = "No Rating"
        
class MovieRaterGUI:

    def __init__(self, parent):

        self.counter = 0
        self.index = 0
        
        #variable set up
        self.v = StringVar()
        self.v.set("No Rating")

        #frames used so you can easily switch between rating frame and summary frame - keeping the search frame
        rating_frame = Frame(root)
        search_frame = Frame(root)
        summary_frame = Frame(root)

        rating_frame.pack(side="top", expand=True)
        search_frame.pack(side="bottom", expand=True)
        summary_frame.pack(side="top", expand = True)

        #rating frame

        #list of ratings for movies
        self.movies = [
        Movie("The Hobbit"),
        Movie("Coraline"),
        Movie("Love, Rosie")]

        #used to display the ratings
        self.ratings = ["No Rating", "Forget it", "2", "3", "4", "Must See"]
        
        #labels
        self.movie_label = Label(rating_frame, text = "Please Rate:", borderwidth = 10)
        self.current_movie = Label(rating_frame, text = self.movies[self.counter].movie, borderwidth = 10)
        self.rating_label = Label(rating_frame, text = "Your rating:", borderwidth = 10)

        self.movie_label.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = W)
        self.current_movie.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)
        self.rating_label.grid(row = 1, column = 0, sticky = W)

        #making radio buttons
        self.radiobutton = []
        self.num_choices = self.ratings
        
        for i in range(len(self.ratings)):  
            self.option = Radiobutton(rating_frame, variable = self.v, value = self.ratings[i], text = self.ratings[i], borderwidth = 10, command = self.update_rating)
            self.radiobutton.append(self.option)
            self.option.grid(row = i+1, column = 1, sticky = W)

        next_btn = Button(rating_frame, text = "Next", borderwidth = 10, command = self.next_movie)
        previous_btn = Button(rating_frame, text = "Previous", borderwidth = 10, command = self.previous_movie)

        next_btn.grid(row = 7, column = 1, sticky = W)
        previous_btn.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)

        #search frame
        
        self.search_label = Label(search_frame, text = "Search for movies with a rating of:", borderwidth = 10)
        self.search_label.grid(row=0, column=0, columnspan=len(self.num_choices))

        for i in range(len(self.num_choices)):
            option = Radiobutton(search_frame, variable = self.v, value = i, text = self.num_choices[i])
            option.grid(row = 1, column = i, sticky = W)

        show_btn = Button(search_frame, text = "Show", borderwidth = 10, command = self.summary_frame)
        show_btn.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = len(self.num_choices))

    def next_movie(self):
        self.counter +=1
        self.current_movie.configure(text = self.movies[self.counter].movie)

        #used so each radio button the user chooses will be saved
        for i in range(len(self.radiobutton)):
            self.radiobutton[i].configure(variable = self.v, text = self.ratings[i], value = self.ratings[i])

        #the default movie rating is no rating for every movie
        self.v.set("No Rating")

    def previous_movie(self):
        self.counter -=1
        self.current_movie.configure(text = self.movies[self.counter].movie)

        #the default movie rating is no rating for every movie
        self.v.set("No Rating")

    def update_rating(self):
        self.movies[self.counter].ratings = self.v.get()
        for element in self.movies:
            print(element.ratings)
        print()
        print('*'*20)
        print()
        

if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = Tk()
    root.title("Movie Ratings")
    radiobuttons = MovieRaterGUI(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Have you tried using `<tk.Frame>.pack_forget()` to remove the frame from the screen?

Comment: where would I add this and would I just write the code for the summary frame underneath the rating frame code??

Comment: consider using ttk.Notebook and having the different frames in two tabs instead?

Comment: if you use `destroy` then you remove also data which you have in this frame - and you couldn't use them. You would have to get data from frame before you destroy it. But i may be better to hide it (`pack_forget`) and then you have access to data in frame and you can always display this frame again. Usually programs have buttons `"Next >>"`, `"<< Previous"` to change frames/steps - but it seems you forgot these buttons.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `destroy` then you destroy also data which you have in this frame - and you couldn't use them. You would have to get data from frame before you destroy it.

But it may be better to remove frame without destroying (`pack_forget`, `grid_forget`) and then you have access to data in frame and you can always display this frame again.

With `grid` it can be simpler to put new element in the same place.

---

**Where put this code?**

Usually programs have buttons `<< Previous`,`Next >>` or `<< Details`, `Summary >>` to change frames/steps - but it seems you forgot these buttons.

Eventually you can use `Notebook` to have frames in `tabs`.

Applications for smartphones usually can slide frames (using fingers) but desktop programs rather don't use this method. And `tkinter` doesn't have special methods for this. It would need much more code with `events` or `drag'&'drop`. Buttons are much simpler to create and simpler to use by users.